# How can I evaluate $\sum_{n=2}^\infty n(n-1)x^n$?

Tags: calculus, power-series

> How can I evaluate $\displaystyle\sum_{n=2}^\infty n(n-1)x^n$?

I know the answer thanks to Wolfram Alpha, but I'm more concerned with how I can derive that answer.

Comment: @TheDemonix_Hermit That's not correct. The sum converges when $|x|<1$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: If $f(x)=\sum x^n$ then $f''(x)=\sum n(n-1)x^{n-2}$

You will need to attend to things like precise limits.

Comment: thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Let $$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n,$$
which converges to $1/(1-x)$ when $|x|<1$. Consider the function $x^2f''(x)$:
$$x^2\left(\frac{d^2}{dx^2}f(x)\right)=x^2\sum_{n=0}^\infty n(n-1)x^{n-2}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty n(n-1)x^n.$$
On the other hand, you can compute  a precise closed-form expression for $x^2f''(x)$ starting from $f(x)=1/(1-x)$. Once you have dealt with rigorously showing the  convergence of the series, this will give you the closed form for the sum you want (after removing the first two terms from the sum, of course).

---

More generally, for a polynomial $p$, we can actually say that
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty p(n)x^n=p(xD)\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n=p(xD)\left(\frac1{1-x}\right),$$
provided that both sides converge. Here, $D$ is the differentiation operator. If you're interested, you can read more about this kind of manipulations in the book [Generatingfunctionology](https://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/DownldGF.html) by Herbert Wilf.

Comment: thank you so much!

Comment: @이창규 No problem.

Answer (score 1):

We can reason$$\sum_{n\ge2}n(n-1)x^n=x^2\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\sum_{n\ge2}x^n=x^2\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\frac{x^2}{1-x}=x^2\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\left(\frac{1}{1-x}-1-x\right)=\frac{2x^2}{(1-x)^3}$$provided $|x|<1$.

Comment: thank you so much!